# ASP.NET MVC - Вызов метода без перехода на страницу

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Доброго времени суток.

Имеется вьюха, на которой есть ActionLink().
Также в контроллере имеется метод

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(string id)
    {
        // TODO: Вызвать запрос о подтверждении.

        var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        var res = await UserManager.DeleteAsync(user);

        return Index(); // Метод можно и переписать
    }
```

Можно ли как-то вызвать этот метод из вьюхи по клику на кнопку\ActionLink\Что-то подобное, чтобы был выполнен метод, но переход между страницами не осуществлялся?

Спасибо.

Comment: Можно - используйте `jQuery.ajax`. "запрос о подтверждении" - делайте на клиенте перед ajax'ом. Какой смысл в await'ах в Вашем коде?

Comment: @Igor, а что не так с await-ами в данном коде? Что Вы имели в виду?
 По идее идут асинхронные вызовы к БД, поток освобождается для обработки следующего запроса.

Comment: да, Вы правы - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ee728598(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно можно. Action Result - абстрактный класс, у которого много потомков.
http://metanit.com/sharp/mvc/3.4.php - можете посмотреть тут.

В вашем случае надо вернуть EmptyResult.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш совет.
Попробовал - get запрос перекинул на пустую страницу (вот вам и EmptyResult)
Воспользовался `return RedirectToAction("Index");` - то, что нужно. Но правильно ли? (Визуально да)

Comment: по сути верно, он перекидывает вас на тот адрес, на котором вы есть, соответственно обновления не происходит.